# Delete entire page from google search

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

So here is the problem, i have created a test site to create new functions, but it was indexed by the google and that is causing problem for the main site with the same data.

I have used webmaster tool and added new request to url removal where i wrote `www.mytestsite.com/index.php` ,  will it acctually delete all this like url's from google search or is there any other way to quickly remove it?

Thanks for help

Comment: Next time you should use a robots.txt to prevent it getting crawled.
http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: I actually used robots.txt with disallow all, but it didnt prevent google from crawling

Comment: Does www.yourtestsite.com and www.yourrealsite.com are really different domain name?

Comment: Yes totally different.

Comment: Does index.php still exists in your page or removed? (Does it returns 404?)

Comment: It looks like Paul and I have roughly the same idea, let them re-crawl with content likely to make them drop you, in a weird way it actually works quicker than using Webmaster Tools at least in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a good answer, just creative, so please don't down-spike me hard. Have you thought of putting up highly worthless, low image high repeated text all over the crawled pages? google will drop you like a stone the next few times they crawl you. Anti-SEO basically, I had a similar problem, crawled my admin test site because my co-worker propped the wrong build with robots allow. It took forever to get them off until I put up a bunch of ad words and Lorem Ipsum. just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to completely remove an entire page from "the Google" search results:

1. On the [Webmaster Tools home page](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=sitemaps&passive=1209600&continue=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/&followup=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/), click the site you want.
2. On the Dashboard, click **Google Index** on the left-hand menu.
3. Click **Remove URLs**.
4. Click **New removal request**.
5. Type the URL of the page you want removed from search results (not the Google search results URL or cached page URL), and then click Continue. How to find the right URL. The URL is case-sensitive—use exactly the same characters and capitalization that the site uses.
6. Click **Yes**, remove this page.
7. Click **Submit** Request.

---

While using a robots.txt to control access to files and directories on your server is helpful, it is not a gaurntee that you won't be indexed.  Robots.txt **CAN BE IGNORED**.
Google won't crawl or index the content of pages blocked by robots.txt, but they still will index your URLs if they appear on other pages on the web.

To entirely prevent a page's contents from being listed in the Google web index (even if other sites link to it) use a **[noindex meta tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710)** or **x-robots-tag**. As long as Googlebot fetches the page, it will see the noindex meta tag and prevent that page from showing up in the web index. The x-robots-tag HTTP header is particularly useful if you wish to limit indexing of non-HTML files like graphics or other kinds of documents.

Comment: Not an answer i needed, i already done that, removed 200 urls through webmaster, but week later, it was back in google search cache.

Comment: I cant give you the bounty, because this answer does not answer may problem or give a new solution how to handle it, still voteup for try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the no-index meta tag:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en

Serve a 410 Gone.

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/i70G2ZAhLmQ/neKEH4spacUJ

Leave your robots txt alone to let Google recrawl. When the URLS are gone from the index, put your robots txt file back in place to block Google crawling entirely.

Also you haven't commented on how this is *actually* causing the parent site problems. Other posters have suggest 301 redirects, which seems plausible if the parent site is losing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Would server side HTTP 301 redirect (Moved Permanently) hep? Here is the link from Google: [301 redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en)

Comment: If you can describe why and what else have you tried, you may get more helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

also you can hide by robot txt file .. and you do not need of delete it. Robots txt file is added in root directory of blogger blog or in any site so that search engine know which part of blog crawl or which is not. search pages are of no use and mostly not allowed to crawl by google  bot and archive can be [disallow](http://5gblogger.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-add-robotstxt-file-in-blogger-2.html) so that they should not crawl in search engine.